# Arrows from child to parent in a tree

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

For the code and image I want to make the lines dashed arrows from child to parent. I've tried using edge to `parent[->, dashed]` constructs, but  can't get it right. I don't need nodes in shapes or boxes, or coloured lines.

Thanks,

David

```
\usepackage{tikz}

 \usetikzlibrary{trees, arrows}

 \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    
    \begin{center}
    \tikz [font=\small,
    
    grow=left, level 1/.style={sibling distance=12em},
    
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=3em}, level distance=5cm, edge to parent/.style={draw,-latex}]
    
    \tikzstyle{bag} = [align=left]
    
    \node[bag] (n00) {Process Description} % root
    
    child { node[bag] (n01) {Connectivity\\ From Process Knowledge}
    
    child { node[bag] (n02) {Process Layout}}
    
    child { node[bag] (n03) {Structural Modelling}}
    
    child { node[bag] (n04) {Adjacency Matrices}}
    }
    child { node[bag] (n05){Causality \\From Process Data}
    
    child { node[bag] (n06) {Cross Correlation}}
    
    child { node[bag] (n07) {Granger Causality}}
    
    child { node[bag] (n08) {Information Theory}}
    
    child { node[bag] (n09) {Bayesian Networks}}
    
    child { node[bag] (n10) {(Machine Learning)}}
    
    };
    
    \end{center}
    
    \caption{Stuff.}
    
    \label{fig:Yang_01}    
    
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image: Text][image]

Comment: your code is incomplete and does not compile

Comment: Hi, try it now - put in preamble requirements, and begin and end document commands.

Answer (score 1):

Please organize your code with a nice format.

Use `edge from parent/.style={draw, dashed, <-}` to get a dashed arrow.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzstyle{bag} = [align=left]

\begin{document}
\tikz [font=\small,
  grow=left,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=12em},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=3em},
  level distance=5cm,
  edge from parent/.style={
    draw, dashed, <-,
  }
]
\node[bag] (n00) {Process Description} % root
child { node[bag] (n01) {Connectivity\\ From Process Knowledge}
  child { node[bag] (n02) {Process Layout}}
  child { node[bag] (n03) {Structural Modelling}}
  child { node[bag] (n04) {Adjacency Matrices}}
}
child { node[bag] (n05){Causality \\From Process Data}
  child { node[bag] (n06) {Cross Correlation}}
  child { node[bag] (n07) {Granger Causality}}
  child { node[bag] (n08) {Information Theory}}
  child { node[bag] (n09) {Bayesian Networks}}
  child { node[bag] (n10) {(Machine Learning)}}
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works. Cool!